# Specifying flat file data types vs using data conversion

Tags: sql-server, ssis

This may be a stupid question but I must ask since I see it a lot... I have inherited quite a few packages in which developers will use the the Data Conversion transformation shape when dumping flat files into their respective sql server tables. This is pretty straight forward however I always wonder why wouldn't the developer just specify the correct data types within the flat file connection and then do a straight load into the the table?

For example:

Typically I will see flat file connections with columns that are `DT_STR` and then converted into the correct type within the package ie: `DT_STR` of length 50 to `DT_I4`. However, if the staging table and the flat file are based on the same schema - why wouldn't you just specify the correct types (`DT_I4`) in the flat file connection? Is there any added benefit (performance, error handling) for using the data conversion task that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good question with not one right answer.  Here is the strategy that I use:

**If the data source is unreliable**

i.e. sometimes int or date values are strings, like when you have the literal word 'null' instead of the value being blank.  I would let the data source be treated as strings and deal with converting the data downstream.

This could mean just staging the data in a table and using the database to do conversions and loading from there.  This pattern avoid the source component throwing errors which is always tricky to troubleshoot.  Also, it avoids having to add error handling into data conversion components.

Instead, if the database throws a conversion error, you can easily look at the data in your staging table to examine the problem.  Lastly, SQL is much more forgiving with date conversions than ssis.

**If the data source is reliable**

If the dates and numbers are always dates and numbers, I would define the datatypes in the connection manager.  This makes it clear what you are expecting from the file and makes the package easier to maintain with fewer components.

Additionally, if you go to the advanced properties of the flatfile source, integers and dates can be set to fast parse which will speed up the read time: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8893ea9d-634c-4309-b52c-6337222dcb39?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**When I use data conversion**

I rarely use the data conversion component.  But one case I find it useful is for converting from / to unicode.  This could be necessary when reading from an ado.net source which always treats the input as unicode, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the output data type in the flat file connection manager in `Advanced` page or right click the source in `Data flow`, `Advanced editor` to change the data type before loading it.

I think one of the benefit is the `conversion` transformation could allow you output the extra column, usually named `copy of ..`, which in some case, you might use both of the two columns. Also, sometimes when you load the data from `Excel source`, all coming with `Unicode`, you need to use `Data conversion` to do the data TF, etc.

Also, just FYI, you could also use `Derived Column` TF to convert the data type.

**UPDATE [Need to be further confirmed]:**

From the `flat file source connection manager`, the maximum length of string type is 255, while in the `Data Conversion` it could be set over 255.

Comment: But if the flat file connection is capable of specifying the correct data types from creation, why not just use that instead of a conversion shape or a derived shape or altering the output data type as you have suggested?

Comment: As I said, the `Data Conversion` will keep both the column before you converted and after conversion, in particular cases, both the original column and the `copy of original` column will be used in the destination.

Comment: And most time, just use `Data Conversion` instead of making any changes to the original flat file.

Comment: But in the scenario where the purpose of the package is to just do a straight load of the data AND if the the file and the table are using the same schema - why deal with a data conversion at all? I still don't understand why the developer wouldn't just specify the correct types in the flat file connection. Unless there is a added benefit in performance that I am not aware of. It seems that there isn't, just wanted to be sure...

Comment: If your source and table sharing exactly the same schema, there is no need to do the data conversion. but usually it is better to use `Data Conversion` to let people know there is a difference between data source and destination, otherwise in your case, if previous developers have changed the data type from the source, you will not even notice there exists data conflicts in your scenario.